# How are 3D objects / fractals colored?

Tags: coloring

I've seen many diagrams of 3D objects being colored using a variety of colors - actually, not just 3D objects, but also things like fractals (the Mandelbrot set, etc...).

I've tried to look up an explanation for this but stuff like "nearness" doesn't really make sense to me... can someone offer a simple explanation as to how things like this are colored?

[image]

Comment: That image uses the escape time algorithm. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plotting_algorithms_for_the_Mandelbrot_set

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look!